# Change button background color due to events and view model property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button that can be at **one** of three modes:

- Normal - No mouse hover and not selected
- Hover - Mouse hover and not selected
- Selected - A property at the view model (DataContext) called IsSelected equals true

This is my current code:

```
<Style x:Key="FlatButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />           
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="125"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border BorderThickness="0"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="12">
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, only the Hover and normal states work.
I tried data triggers, visual state manager but I'm new to WPF and couldn't make it work.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the WPF binding errors? You need to turn that on in Visual Studio options and you can see them the Console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IsSelected Trigger Value is missing. If you want to stick with a button use

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

I will recommend to use `ToggleButton` and Trigger on IsChecked Property

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Style="{StaticResource FlatButtonStyle}"/>

<Style x:Key="FlatButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="125"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border BorderThickness="0"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                CornerRadius="12">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try useing Toggle Button instead of Button control. it has by default IsChecked state. Here is an exaple of how to use toggle button

http://miteshsureja.blogspot.ae/2011/12/wpf-toggle-button.html

Comment: But it won't solve the mouse over style. When the button is "checked" the mouse over must not effect...