# WPF change button background from viewmodel

Tags: wpf

In my WPF application user control i have 5 buttons. I have created DependencyProperty for Background color which is shared among all 5 buttons.

On load based on some condition i am giving background color to all buttons.

When i click on particular button i just want to change background color of it. The problem is due to shared background property its changing all buttons background color.

I want to change only clicked button background. How to do this?

[Change button background color due to events and view model property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033259). This is not relevant to my question. 
My question is how to change background color of a button on click while its having common background binding property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change button background color due to events and view model property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033259/change-button-background-color-due-to-events-and-view-model-property)

Comment: No its quite different from my scenario

Comment: Bind to a list of colors instead of just one